# iPhone: Chart works as expected on iPhone but not on iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

I am making a Universal app which works both for iPhone and iPad.

I am generating Line charts for my Reports.

When the report data changes the changes are shown properly in iPhone, but the same code and same data when used on iPad doesnt change the chart.

I am capturing the image out of the chart and putting it into webView using an HTML String.

New Images are generated properly in case of both iPhone and iPad.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution.

I was giving the same name every time to the newly created image. So even though new image was created the webview I think cached the previous image. So added a current timestamp in image naming convention .

Hope this helps :)